# Is the following a safe and correct way of using a cookie?

Tags: express, cookies, setcookie

I am making a website where a user can create a post, edit their post and delete their post. There is a homepage(much like the Stack Exchange homepage) where every new post is shown.

When a user clicks on a post, they see options to edit and delete the post only if they made the post. To verify whether or not they made the post, I realised that I need to implement a way to know which user has requested a document. I can't pass the users username with the request as the request is a get request. And as far as I know, a different user can just type in the get request in the url of their browser with that users username and have the options to edit or delete the post.

If this is wrong, please let me know.

So, I have decided to send a cookie when the user logs in. In the cookie, is it okay and safe to include the following.

```
set_cookie: user_name=username
```

Where username is retrieved from the POST request that is sent when the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, cookies can be changed by users, so this is not a good security mechanism.

If you want something like this, the best alternative is to use something called a 'session'. Most frameworks have support for them.

Sessions still use cookies, but they store the data on the server-side. The cookie contains a unique string that is impossible to guess.

Comment: Thanks for explaining sessions. I did read about them but couldn’t exactly figure out why to use them instead of cookies. 

Also, if I use httponly in my cookie, does that still mean that users can change the data of that Cooke?

Comment: @Seeker yes. Anything sent to a browser can be manipulated by a user.

Comment: Sorry to keep barraging you with questions. Just wanted to confirm that my understanding of sessions was correct. So, I send a cookie to the browser with a string of alphabets and numbers(or just numbers or alphabets) that is not easy to guess. Then this way, another user can’t edit their cookie details to pretend to be another user. Is this right? But if I just used a users username, anyone can edit their cookies with someone else’s username and pretend to be that person. So, sessions is just the name given to a cookie where the cookie doesn’t contain personal data explicitly.

Comment: @Seeker, yes you got that right. I wrote a blog post some time ago about JWTs that also explains cookies and sessions in the first paragraphs if this helps: https://evertpot.com/jwt-is-a-bad-default/

Comment: That is really well written! I really like that you point out that sessions are not different from cookies. Everything I read on the internet keeps trying to make them two different things, rather than just saying that a session is a special type of cookie. I also had one more question. Should I be generating a new session id for the same user every time they log in or can the session id remain the same.

Comment: @Seeker. Every time a user logs in or out, you should destroy the old session and create a new session with a new id. Thanks for the nice words!